# How to evaluate results of user annotations vs classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a data set with around 250 data points. I previously automatically labeled the data using an established classifier. Every data point is assigned with one of three possible labels. I then conducted a user study where ten users labeled 25 randomly chosen data points (from the 250, none used twice).

I now have the labels of the classifier and the user annotated labels. How do i measure the agreement of both the users and the classifier? I don't know if i just can use Precision / Recall and F1-score as metrics to evaluate the agreement of the users and the classifier?

Comment: You might want to explore Cohen's kappa. I do not think precision and recall work well with three-valued variables but I might be wrong.

Comment: I thought about Cohen's kappa but i am not sure if that is possible with the 10 different users. I would have to use the total of 10x25 user annotations as one set and the classifier as another?

Comment: There is a multi-rater version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa

Comment: +1 for mdewey Check out Joe Fleiss's text on this subject.